# 32-bit or 64-bit Zoom?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, zoom-meeting

Should I install the 64-bit or the 32-bit version of Zoom if my laptop computer is 64-bit? Will it use unnecessary RAM to install the 64-bit version? I'm looking for the fastest experience and also would sometimes like to use other applications like Google Chrome and Discord while in a Zoom meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom 32-bit came out first if I recall correctly and Zoom 64-bit came out a bit later.

I have used both and use Zoom 64-bit now on my two Windows 10 computers and my one Windows 11 Insider Computer.

Zoom does not use unnecessary memory that I can see. Little additional memory being used.

Zoom (on the computer) performs the same (within reason) 64-bit vs. 32-bit.

I use Zoom with Chromium Edge which has the same underlying engine as Chrome.

I suggest using Zoom 64-bit as 64-bit applications are now much more common.

Other:  I have been converting most app I can to 64-bit (Office, Java, and all my other apps that have 64-bit versions).

On the Download Page, both 32-bit and 64-bit are available.  If you choose to use 32-bit, it works as well as 64-bit (and vice-versa).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!